# How to log a message from a string variable in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I am trying to log a message form a string variable , below is the code I used

```
std::string s = "ss";//std::to_string(FPaths::GetPath("../"));
 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, *s);
```

but it's not working, Can someone tell me how to do this ?
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally I am answering my own question here.

It doesn't compile because I need to use the TEXT Macro before giving a string into UE_LOG.

```
FString s = "ss";
 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *s);

 //or

 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("ss"));

 //this should work
 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *FPaths::GetPath("../"));
```

should work with Unreal's version of Datatypes instead of using the std library

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it's correct :P And try to use Unreal's string, array, map...etc. instead of std ones since Unreal has its own magic...

Comment: Only the std algorithms are compatible with Unreal's containers since they support begin() and end(), otherwise I think you should use Unreal's equivalents.

Comment: `UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *s);` 

Answer (score 6):

If you really have to than you can convert std::string to FString and than log that like this.

```
std::string someString = "Hello!";
FString layerName(someString .c_str());
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *layerName);
```